# Using Application Loader to upload PhoneGap project

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, phonegap-build, application-loader

I have got an .ipa file generated from using a phonegap build. I am trying to upload the ipa file using the application uploader. I have a developer license, so all I need to do is link my ipa to the app on itunes connect.

The problem I'm having is when I click "deliver your app" in application loader and choose the ipa file.. The following screen is displayed:

[image: wrong app loading in deliver your app]

This is the wrong app.. how do I change this to my ImpactSafety app?

Can anyone offer a solution to this problem. Thanks in advance.

Update 1:

This is my app within the iTunes Connect. Notice it is a the "Prepare for Submission" stage:

[image: impact safety app at prepare for submission stage]

Still when I open application loader and deliver my app.. it still offers a different app that I have in the iTunes Connect space.

Answer (score 0):

For load app to your iTunesConnect site, your app must have status "Prepare for Submission":

1) Open itunesconnect.apple.com

2) Find your app and click him

3) In left column find "VERSION OR PLATFORM" link and choose "iOS"

4) Set your version number

5) Fill all necessary fields

6) Restart application loader and find your app

7) Try reload your IPA with Application Loader

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Will run through these steps and report back to you! :)

Comment: Is there anything I need to do locally on my mac to do with Provisions?

Comment: What you have stated does not tackle the initial problem. The app that is being suggested after I click "Deliver your app" is the "Learnfest" - Another app that I don't want to use. It should be "Impact Safety" but there is no option to select that one.

Comment: It seems, your IPA is compiled with Learnfest bundle, not with Impact Safety bundle. Check your bundle in Info.plist and recompile your IPA

Comment: Second question, how you generating you IPA file?

Comment: I've generated my file using phonegap. Theres no option to assign a info.plist via that method I don't think. Any idea what to do to change the bundle?

Comment: @Chris Try change bundle in PhoneGap site. http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/3-create-your-app/desktop/

Comment: @CReaTuS thanks, your solution worked for me. I had used a bundle that was tied to another app.